# All arborvitaes dead!

Tags: shrubs

I live in Central New Jersey. My Dad wanted these trees in 2001.  They were beautiful and healthy until last summer, 2021.

First the trees along the back fence began dying, quickly.  About every 2nd tree.  Then, the rest died soon after. Now I noticed the side ones are going too.

I also noticed in the summer a neighbor who lives a few streets away had completely dead arborvitaes all at once. 6 total.  I surely would've noticed his dying had they been slowly dying. But his went all at once also.

I thought perhaps our inundation of the japanese lantern fly, since newest to our area, may have had something to do with this strange turn of their health? Or is there another type of fungus or insect that is partial to my poor arbs?

I am so upset. The cost to replace is so out of my reach, and my yard looks dead now.
**Sad**......

Comment: "They were beautiful and healthy until last summer, 2021." Huh? Typo?

Comment: pictures please

Comment: Good bet it's the Spotted Lantern fly. If only they stayed with their favorite, the smelly Tree of Heaven.